# How to change DateTimePicker format in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using windows forms, C#.

I have `button1`, `lable1` and `dateTimePicker1`.

The flowing code displays the date as "10-12-2015" in `lable1` text :

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");            
}
```

How can I display the date and the name of the day as " Thursday 10-12-2015" in `lable1` text?

Please help. thank you

Comment: Please copy your question title, paste it into google, and select the first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dddd dd-MM-yyyy");            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dddd dd-MM-yyyy");            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

type the following in a Console app and you will see mess around with the following

```
label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dddd dd-MM-yyyy");
```

> Yields Thursday 10-12-2015"

or

```
label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddd dd-MM-yyyy");
```

> Yields Thur 10-12-2015"